# Groovy Variable $ Dollar Sign in JSON

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I've got a JSON file that I am slurping with groovy.

```
{
"team": "${GLOBAL_TEAM_NAME}",
"jobs": [
    {
```

In the JSON above is a property 'team' that contains a groovy-like variable I want to be resolved at runtime.

```
teamList.each { tl -> 

try
{
    def teamSlurper = new JsonSlurperClassic()
    def t = teamSlurper.parseText(tl.text)

    println "*********************"
    println "PROVISIONING JOB FOR: " + t.team
```

Output:

> PROVISIONING JOB FOR: ${GLOBAL_TEAM_NAME}

The above outputs the raw value, but I would like it to resolve the global variable that has been defined for the system.

How can I resolve `${GLOBAL_TEAM_NAME}` to its actual system value?

Comment: Using regex is your safest bet I'd say. Groovy isn't going to evaluate that token straight away (cuz that'd be unsafe as hell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [Groovy Templates](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/template-engines.html).

```
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurperClassic()
def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
def binding = ["GLOBAL_TEAM_NAME": "Avengers"]
def json = '{"team":"${GLOBAL_TEAM_NAME}"}'
def t = slurper.parseText(engine.createTemplate(json).make(binding).toString())
t.team // "Avengers"
```